# How to create a column with today's date in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
order id    purchase_date
123         4/2/18
234         4/4/18
345         4/10/18
456         4/13/18
```

I want to add an additional column called "today" in my existing dataframe. Can anyone help me to understand how to do it? I am using python 2.7.15 version.

```
id    purchase_date   today
123   4/2/18          6/29/18
234   4/4/18          6/29/18
345   4/10/18         6/29/18
456   4/13/18         6/29/18
```

Comment: How are generating data currently ? Can you add related code ?

Comment: The data is a sample data. I already have columns "id" and "purchase_date".